# What can somebody do with just name and passport number?

Tags: breach

What is the risk if just full name and passport number were to be leaked? just those two pieces of information and nothing else.

Comment: Different countries have different conventions when it comes to the format of a passport number - so one _might_ be able to derive the origin/country where it has been issued and therefore now knows the nationality of, lets say John Doe.  If the name of that person is quite unusual and unique,  one could check if a lookup in the white pages/facebook/linkedIn to see if more info can be obtained, possibly yielding a living address or simlar info..

Comment: Does this relate to the recent chinese citizens leak?..

Comment: In the US SSN is such a powerful piece of information, it's been abused to no end. But again its country dependent. In Russia just your name and passport number won't get you anywhere at all, except it will allow you to deduce the region and a rough date the person was born in.